# Python 3 - using multiple times choice

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do i use 'choice' multiple times in a single command line.
I want to use the command 'choice' like following -

```
>>> l
['9', '10', '1', '2', '3']
>>> choice(l)
'2'
>>> choice(l)*3
'222'
```

I need to generate three different values from `l` and not three times the same number.

Comment: I assume that `choice()` is from the standard Python `random` module, but you _really_ should mention that in your question, eg with a `from random import choice` statement at the start of your code block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the values can be the same then you just run `random.choice()` three times (in a loop, for example).

But if they need to be *different*, use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) instead and have it pick 3 values *that are different* for you:

```
random.sample(l, 3)
```

Using `random.choice()` repeatedly can lead to values being picked more than once, `random.sample()` will ensure that the 3 values picked are unique.

Answer (score -3):

```
[ choice(l) for x in range(3)]
```

Comment: Don't repost when you have been downvoted. Edit to explain why your answer is correct instead.

Comment: I didn't vote on your first attempt, but I'd not be surprised if whomever voted would come around and vote this down again, as there are caveats; you can easily pick the same number more than once using this.

Comment: Also, this is a code-only answer; without an explanation, this is hardly helpful.